# Is there a way to cd into a random directory in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I wish to figure out a way to change the working directory to a random directory in bash. By this I mean a pre-created directory that is not specified in any way. I've already tried just using   `cd *` , but it doesn't recognize the wildcard character unless I have a letter in front of it, ie, `cd a*` . Does anyone know a quick, easy way to do this? A one-line solution would be great, but any answer will do. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't quite got it. You using bash or Python? Or both?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was coding python a couple hours ago, and got mixed up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
shopt -s nullglob
dirs=(*/)
[[ $dirs ]] && cd -- "${dirs[RANDOM%${#dirs[@]}]}"
```

Whenever you want a single line, use a function. This also allows using locals and has other advantages.

Comment: Definitely the best answer, in every way (except when there are no directories!)... maybe `failglob` would be better than `nullglob` here. `+1` anyway.

Comment: How about just add `((${#dirs[@]})) && ` in front of `cd` so as to avoid a division by zero?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Not sure what you mean, there should be no division by zero either way. When it comes to determining set arguments `((${#x[@]}))` tends to be one of the slowest because it involves counting the arguments. Most of the good methods involve the `+` PE. Sadly, bash doesn't yet support `[[ -v x[0] ]]` (though ksh93 has for a while). I've put a pretty good list of methods here http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/083

Comment: The modulo operator yields a division by zero when there are no dirs. As a dirname can't be empty and as you don't want to count the number of elements in array `dirs`, then `[[ $dirs ]] && ` could do as well.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Ah right. I suppose regurgitating my stock answer is bad (the x[@] doesn't generalize to this case). I think cd guarantees success under normal circumstances too, so `! ${x:+cd "${x[RANDOM%${#x[@]}]}"} || ...` might be yet another alternate, but this sort of thing isn't very clear as I alluded to earlier...